# JavaScript/JQuery DataTables - Inserting tools (PDF,Copy,CSV, Print) with Existing JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an existing JQuery code for DataTable which lets the hidden first column be in order of Descending.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
                  order:[[0,"desc"]],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": [ 0 ],
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        }
                    ]
                } );
            } );
</script>
```

And I want to add this lines of codes, which I copied from [DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

How should it be done? I tried doing this:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
                  order:[[0,"desc"]],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": [ 0 ],
                            "visible": false,
                            "searchable": false
                        }
                    ],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ]
                } );
            } );
</script>
```

But it won't work. Can someone help me correct the format? 
I would like to add another relevant information to be added too. On the Print button as well as PDF button, I would like it to be in Landscape mode and with Added custom message. Like this:

```
            extend: 'pdfFlash',
            messageTop: 'PDF created by Buttons for DataTables.'
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.  `buttons: [  'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ],` is exactly what you should do. And then just use a literal with `extend`instead of a string if you want to custumize the `pdf` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create array of buttons, try this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        order: [[0, "desc"]],
            "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'copy' },
            { extend: 'csv' },
            { extend: 'excel' },
            { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },
            { extend: 'print' }
        ]
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you help me where to insert that lines of codes on mine. My First code is on the upper part. I really don't know the correct syntax on executing your line of codes on mine. Thank you.

Comment: Updated for you

Comment: If true so please vote me and check my answer with V mark